# How to use C# enumeration values in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, enums

I have got an enumeration in C# ie something like Category.cs.
In a dropdownlist we are binding values.
So if the user selects some specific value in dropdown it will hide one div.
So i want to get the enumeration value in javascript ie want to compare the enumeration value with one selected value in javascript.

Mahesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have such `enum` with numeric values:

```
public enum Colors
{
   Yellow = 1,
   Red,
   Blue,
   Green,
   Purple
}
```

First of all, in the code behind (Page_Load event) register JavaScript code that will build client side structure that hold the same data:

```cs
string strJS = string.Format("var arrColors = {{{0}}}; ",
    string.Join(", ", Enum.GetNames(typeof(Colors)).ToList().ConvertAll(key =>
{
    return string.Format("{0}: {1}", key, (int)((Colors)Enum.Parse(typeof(Colors), key)));
}).ToArray()));
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "enum", strJS, true);
```

Now `arrColors` is JS variable with both keys and values of your `enum`.

To use it, have such code for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function SelectionChanged(oDDL) {
      var selectedValue = oDDL.value;
      var enumValue = arrColors[selectedValue] || "N/A";
      alert("enum value for '" + selectedValue + "' is: " + enumValue);
   }
</script>
```

And the drop down should look like this:

```html
<select onchange="SelectionChanged(this);">
    <option>Select..</option>
    <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="Green">Green</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why not use JSON encoding of an enum? Surely there must be a way to turn an enum to JSON and then pass that to the page?

Comment: @Raynos interesting idea.. I prefer to stick with what I know but I now found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) - the final result should be the same so the benefit is just doing it in more "elegant" way.. :)

Comment: @Shadow: Thanks for your reply. So how can i check the selected value is Yellow.

Comment: @mahesh - for this you don't need the C# enum at all, just such a line of code: `if (selectedValue == "Yellow") { alert("you selected yellow"); }`

Comment: @Shadow: i want to use that enum . Suppose if i change the enum value yellow to yyellow with the same value 1, then also it can be compare from javascript with out changing the javascript function

Comment: @mahesh sorry I lost you now. Can you please explain better what you're trying to do? Maybe add some example in your original question?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I would also say its more maintainable as other developers will have a better understanding of how C# construct relate to JavaScript constructs through the JSON serialiser then your personal "non-standard" ad-hoc translation.

Comment: @mahesh check againts the value 1 directly.

Comment: @mahesh do you mean `if (enumValue == 1) { alert("you selected yellow"); }`? (Thanks Raynos for the idea!)

Comment: @Shadow: what i mean is, if me change the value of enum ie yellow to yyelloe then how can i check in javascript

Comment: @mahesh change the value of enum where? how? What will change it?

Comment: @Shadow: What i am trying is , if i edit the enum class ie changing the spelling or something like that, then also it should be working without editing the javascript function

Comment: @mahesh using the code in my answer you'll only have to change the `value` of the relevant `<option>` in the drop down or alternatively generate those options on the fly. The function only check the selected value and look for match `enum` value.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Enum.GetNames(typeof(yourenumerationtype))` - returns an array of strings, which represents enumeration items' names

Comment: Yep but I believe he's after the value of each name.