# Selecting Enum items on AJAX call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, enums

I am working on action result which returns JSON data to view and then loads on textFields by AJAX call

Action:

```
public ActionResult loadInf(string custm)
{
    int smclientbranchid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["smclientbranchid"]);
    var query = (from parent in db.Customer
                 join child in db.CustomerAddress on parent.CustomerId equals child.CustomerId
                 where parent.SMClientBranchId == smclientbranchid && parent.NIC == custm
                 select new SalesVM
                 {
                    Indicator = parent.Indicator,
                    //code removed
                 }).ToList();
    return Json(query);
}
```

In View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Indicator, 
    new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(ColorTypes))),
    "<Select>", 
    new { @class = "form-control", id ="Indicator" })

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnSearchCus").click(function () {
            var custm = $('#custm').val();
            $.ajax({
                cashe: 'false',
                type: "POST",
                data: { "custm": custm },
                url: '@Url.Action("LoadCustomerInfo", "Sales")',
                dataType: 'json',  // add this line
                "success": function (data) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        var vdata = data;
                        $("#Indicator").val(vdata[0].Indicator);
                        //code removed
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am getting data right and also loading right except the "Indicator" field, which is of type enum.

How can I select an enum list item from the data I get.

For example:

> 0,1,2,3 index order

Comment: What does `vdata[0].Indicator` output? Does it match the value of one of the options in the dropdown? And why are you returning a list when you appear to only need one item (i.e  `.FirstOrDefault()` rather than `.ToList()`)

Comment: Your ajax calls `LoadCustomerInfo()` on `SalesController` and passes a parameter named `custm` yet the method you have shown is `loadInf(string nm)`. You don't appear to have included the correct method.

Comment: thanks for reply, yes it does have matching order,

Comment: What do you mean by _yes it does have matching order_? What does `vdata[0].Indicator` output? Does it match exactly the `value` attributes of one of your options?

Comment: i have updated the questionsir,,, on loading data, no value appears to be selected

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537271/how-to-use-c-sharp-enumeration-values-in-javascript

Comment: What bit about _"What does vdata[0].Indicator output"_ do you not understand? Put a `console.log( vdata[0].Indicator);` in your code and check what the value is and compare it with the html generated for the options in the `select`) And read my second comment - you have shown the wrong code (your call a method named `LoadCustomerInfo()` not `loadInf()`)

Comment: I agree we do need to know whether `vdata[0].Indicator` is a string representation of the enum or the integer value.  Either way, please see the new answer I have posted.  Your jquery doesn't select the correct value because the `value=""` attributes on your options aren't populated.

Comment: @Coulton, It does not matter if there is no `value` attribute, using `.val()`  falls back to the value of the text in the option.

Comment: Sorry you're right I just tried it again.  I think that might confirm that the value returned back in the JSON is the integer, and if so then he will need to set the `value`.  When I return an enum back using `Json()` it does indeed return back the `int` representation of the enum value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be setting the `Value` attributes against all of the `option` values for the select list.

Use the following for your dropdown box to select by the text representation of the value:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Indicator, Enum.GetValues(typeof(ColorTypes)).Cast<ColorTypes>().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ToString(), Value = x.ToString() }), new { @class = "form-control", id = "Indicator" })
```

Or use the following for it to select by the `integer` value:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Indicator, Enum.GetValues(typeof(ColorTypes)).Cast<ColorTypes>().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ToString(), Value = ((int)x).ToString() }), new { @class = "form-control", id = "Indicator" })
```

This will allow your `.Val()` jQuery code to select the correct one.

Comment: thanks for reply, +1 for your time and help, i will check it and accept the answer

Comment: No problem.  Let me know how it goes, I just tested it and it works OK :)

Comment: @Coulton. I think you are misunderstanding OP code. The ajax call is passing a value from another control (probably another dropdown) in order to return an object of type `SalesVM` and using the properties of `SalesVM` to update other controls in the view, including a dropdown with `<select id="Indicator" ..>` OP claims other control values are updated correctly but `Indicator` is not, meaning that the value of `Indicator` being returned does not match the value of one of the options.

Comment: I see what you're saying... 1 sec

Comment: Please see the update, it should work depending on what the value of `vdata[0].Indicator` is.  If it is the __text__ representation, then it should work.  If it is the number representation, let me know

Comment: oh!!! great it worked, thanks alot,,,,i am slow in thinking and stupidest in programming, i know.....i appreciate you people's efforts

Answer (score 1):

If you retrieving string variable nm  (0,1,2,3...) - would be better to change the type to int and try cast your integer variable to `Enum` type that you have.

```
public ActionResult loadInf(int nm)
{
    ColorTypes enumValue = (ColorTypes) nm;
.......
```

You can take a look about details to this article: http://www.jarloo.com/convert-an-int-or-string-to-an-enum/